# How can i resize image in table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, resize

How can I do something like in the picture in a table ?
I was thinking that i can add a table view with a image and more custom cells.[image]
My problem is:How can i resize image by dragging like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to set the imageView contentMode to aspectFill, so that the image will expand automatically when the imageView frame change.

This need a little setup for your views constraints though, some references:

1. http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/
2. [how to expand image on UITableView like in CNN app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369124/how-to-expand-image-on-uitableview-like-in-cnn-app)

I have setup my own using the methods described in the first link above.

Comment: ok! and how i can drag the image?
I'm new in ios, and don't know exactly what i have to do...

Comment: If you set the constraints right, the image can be "dragged". It is hard to explain the whole thing about autolayout, therefore I suggest you read the apple doc about auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Prototype cells and an UIImageview within a scrollview for zoom in and zoom out feature. for expansion behavior of the table view cell u can refer these link :

https://github.com/xerxes235/HVTableView